# Android - Relative path generator of all view present inside rootview hierarchy of any Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

**Background**

In android layout file there or lot of UI elements and view group. Sometimes we do not need to give `id` value ( unique identifier ) to views. In such scenarios we can't find the view by saying `findViewByid()`. hence we cannot manipulate them.

**Question is**

How we can generate a path for all view of any activity, Example is below:

`content>LinearLayout-0>RelativeLayout-3>LinearLayout-0>TextView-2`

The meaning of above line is

1. Content is main layout
2. LinearLayoutis top most layout
3. RelativeLayout-3 is 3rd child of top most layout
4. LinearLayout is child of 3rd RelativeLayout
5. TexView-2 is child of LinearLayout which is 3rd RelativeLayout child of topmost LinearLayout.

So basically I'm looking for function like below:

```
String path = getViewPath(view);
```

and

```
View view = findViewByPath(path)
```

**Use case:**

Actually server will broadcast some command to mobile app by menting path of view ,

then mobile app will find the view from the path and change the property of the views

Comment: The question is not very clear from the title. Do you want to get the view Hierarchy of any `View` object?

Comment: No, I want to get relative path of all view present in view Hierarchy , Like depth of view inside layout top most layout

Comment: Check my answer Lavekush! There is an alternative to paths. Only a Tag is needed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below the solution for above question, I have created both method for getting view path, and getting view by path.

Cheers!!!

```
    package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.view.Window;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class CustomViewIdManager {


  private static final String ACTIVITY_CLASS_SEPARATOR = "@";
  private static final String VIEW_SEPARATOR = ">";
  private static final String VIEW_POSITION_SEPARATOR = ":";
  private static final String MAIN_CONTENT_LAYOUT_NAME = "content";


  /**
   * Find given view path in activity hierarchy
   *
   * @param view
   * @param activity
   * @return Path given view
   */
  public static String generateViewPathInActivityViewHierarchy(View view, Activity activity) {

    String path = "";
    View currentView = view;
    ViewParent currentParent;

    do {
      currentParent = currentView.getParent();
      if (currentView.getId() == Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT) {
        path = activity.getLocalClassName() + ACTIVITY_CLASS_SEPARATOR + MAIN_CONTENT_LAYOUT_NAME + path;
        break;
      } else {
        path = VIEW_SEPARATOR + currentView.getClass().getSimpleName() + VIEW_POSITION_SEPARATOR + getSelfIndexInParent((View) currentParent, currentView) + path;
      }
      currentView = (View) currentView.getParent();
    } while (true);

    return path;
  }


  /**
   * Finding the view by given path in activity view hierarchy
   * @param path
   * @param activity
   * @return
     */
  public static View findViewByCustomPath(String path, Activity activity) {

    String[] activitySplitting = path.split(ACTIVITY_CLASS_SEPARATOR);
    String[] viewSplitting = activitySplitting[1].split(VIEW_SEPARATOR);

    View viewLooker = null;

    if (viewSplitting[0].equalsIgnoreCase(MAIN_CONTENT_LAYOUT_NAME)) {
      viewLooker = ViewUtil.getContentView(activity);
    }

    return viewFinder(viewLooker, Arrays.copyOfRange(viewSplitting, 1, viewSplitting.length));

  }

  public static View viewFinder(View view, String[] restPath) {

    View viewToSendBack;

    String singleView = restPath[0];
    String[] viewPositioningSplitting = singleView.split(VIEW_POSITION_SEPARATOR);
    viewToSendBack = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(Integer.parseInt(viewPositioningSplitting[1]));

    if (restPath.length > 1) {
      return viewFinder(viewToSendBack, Arrays.copyOfRange(restPath, 1, restPath.length));
    } else {
      return viewToSendBack;
    }
  }


  /**
   * This will calculate the self position inside view
   *
   * @param parent
   * @param view
   * @return index of child
   */
  public static int getSelfIndexInParent(View parent, View view) {

    int index = -1;
    if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
      ViewGroup viewParent = (ViewGroup) parent;

      for (int i = 0; i < viewParent.getChildCount(); ++i) {
        View child = viewParent.getChildAt(i);
        ++index;

        if (child == view) {
          return index;
        }
      }
    }

    return index;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution to this would be to use a `ViewGroup`'s [getChildAt()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)) and [getChildCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildCount()) methods.

So, you can cast each of your desired `View` as a `ViewGroup` and can call the above methods. Though, this won't return a `String` path. But you could still obtain a relative hierarchy and work your way up to your specific use case.

Comment: This answer will not fulfil my desire, as I didn't no the location of child at  runtime. Actually server will send some command to mobile app by menting path of view , then mobile app will find the view and change it property. and even from count or number u can't predict which type of layout it is

Comment: I'll try and think more about this and get back to you. Hope you solve your problem soon!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel. If you need the reference to your Views there is a lot of ways to get than making path to views. If you want the reference from Views here is what to do:

#### From Xml:

If your views were made using `XML` then the best way to refer to those `View` is by setting an id like:

```
    android:id="@+id/my_id"
```

And when you want to refer to that `View` in code we use:

```
    (AnyParentOfTheView).findViewById(R.id.my_id);
```

#### From Code (Dynamically):

If your Views were created dynamically then we cannot use the method `(Parent).findViewById(int id)`.

**Alternatively**

When you create Views dynamically we can refer to them using what we call Tags. Unlike ids, Tags are set in code to your views dynamically. A tag can be any Java `Object` but we usually use Strings but you can associate a tag with any `Object` and later refer to the view using the method `findViewWithTag(Object tag)`

Example:

```
    .......
    TextView myTextView=new TextView(this);
    myTextView.setTag("txt");
    .......
```

And when we want to refer to our `TextView` in code we call the method like:

```
    TextView myTextView=(TextView)findViewWithTag("txt");
```

And like that we get reference to our `View` so if you want the `TextView` you can do that. The `View` class even support a way to get a view tag in code like:

```
    String myTag=myTextView.getTag();
```

Best methods for your use case are:

```
    setTag(Object obj)
    setTag (int key, Object tag)
    getTag(int key)
    getTag()
    findViewWithTag()
```

To get more documentation and elaboration on using these methods and more. Check the documentation 
[HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Comment: This won't be work in my case, We are not creating any dynamic view, View manipulation done from server, Server will send some view properties to mobile device and then mobile find the view from path and change the properties.

Comment: Why does your server want a path instead of just a "tag" for the View so as to change the properties? Gimme a reason for that?

Comment: Dont worry I have implimented solution. please check my answer. cheers

Comment: Mmmh let's assume I have understood!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am over simplifying but it sounds like what you want is the [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dom.asp). 
Using the it you would be able to find all children and their paths and query the structure.

If indeed this answers your requirement then you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083545/using-dom-to-parse-an-android-xml-layout-file) or like suggested in a different answer by using ViewGroup functions building your own DOM object from the root view (you will use [get root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879743/get-parents-view-from-a-layout) and [get children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395168/android-get-children-inside-a-view).